# How do I move an array from inside an array into a new array - python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to put an array from inside an array into another array.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

y = [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
```

How do I move `[j,k,l]` into `x`,
to form an outcome of:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

y = [[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
```

So far I have tried,

```
import numpy as np

x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

y = [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]

x = x + y[1]

print(x)
```

However it caused an out come of:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], 13, 14, 15]
```

And `13,14,15` is not an array?

Please help.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use the append method, the syntax is like this:

```
list1 = list1.append(list2[n])
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing `x = x + y[1]` extends `x` by adding to it the *elements* of `y[1]`.

What you want is instead to add a list of the elements of `y[1]`.

```
In [1]: x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
   ...:
   ...: y = [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]

In [2]: x = x + [y[1]]

In [3]: x
Out[3]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Note that doing `x = x + y` creates a new list and assigns it to `x`, whereas you can modify `x` directly instead by doing `x.append(...)` as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **append** function, as follows:

```
     x.append(y[1])
```